# Maximized rectangular area dimensions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A homeowner wants to fence a rectangular garden using 64 ft of fencing. The side of an out building will be used as one side of the rectangle.

How do I determine the dimensions for which area is maximized?  How do I calculate the maximum area?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  What have you attempted?  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Hint

We have $2a+b=64,b=64-2a$

$$ab=a(64-2a)=2\cdot16^2-2(a-16)^2\le2\cdot16^2$$

Comment: @NF, I was searching for the typo, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let one of the sides touching the wall have length $x$. Then the side lengths of the rectangle are $x$ and $64-2x$ (so that $x + (64-2x) + x = 64$ ft). Thus you want to maximise
$$A(x) = x(64-2x),$$
which is maximal when $A'(x) = 0$, i.e., when $x=16$.

Consequently, the dimensions which maximise the area are $16$ and $64-2(16)=32$, and the maximum area is $16\times 32 = 512$ square feet.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of geometry.

Let $a+2b =\overline {AB}$, area of rectangle: $A:=ab$.

Consider a Thales circle above $\overline{AB}$, i.e. a circle with centre $M$, midpoint of $ \overline {AB}$, and radius $(1/2)\overline{AB}$.

Pick any point $C$ on this circle. $\triangle ABC$ is a right triangle with right angle at $C$.

Let $ h_{AB}$ be the height on $ \overline {AB}$.

We have:

$h_{AB}^2=a(2b)$;

$\max h_{AB}$ occurs when $h_{AB}$ passes through $M$, i.e. when $a=2b$.

For $a+2b=64$, and $a=2b$, we get $a= 32.$

Maximum area:

$A= (1/2) \max h_{AB}^2= (1/2) \max(a2b) =(1/2)32^2.$